# how to get or set git global config using libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, winui-3, libgit2sharp

I am learning C# and trying to develop a git client, currently using the library: libgit2sharp,

Now I have a requirement to display and support modification of git global config, such as "user.name" or "user.email".

bug I did not find the corresponding documentation in the official [wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki)

One more question, I am running the program on a Windows Arm64 device and libgit2sharp doesn't seem to support it, is that true?

Windows Arm64 Error Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtmnR.png)

Comment: One more question, I am running the program on a Windows Arm64 device and libgit2sharp doesn't seem to support it, is that true

Comment: You should add your comment into your question. And yes, it's very possible that some library doesn't support Arm64. But a Windows Arm64 machine can support x86 or x64 code.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1573) on the GitHub repo might help you.